# Use the TeamViewer VPN to make a proxy server

Tags: windows-7, vpn, proxy, teamviewer

I can use TeamViewer's VPN to establish a VPN between me and my home PC, it works fine.
Now I'd like to transform my home PC in a proxy so I can use my home connection too, the scheme would then be:

```
me-->home pc-->destination
destination-->home pc --> me
```

I guess I'll have to install a proxy server on my home PC, as I can't see any proxy function on TeamViewer right?
Mind, that I want to use EVERY protocol, so an HTTP proxy server like squid would not work.  I also want it to be very efficient, so no packet checking, no authentication (TeamViewer already performs it), just plain take packet/send packet, but through the TeamViewer VPN.

Comment: As a teamviewer user you always wait for the next release to incorporate a turnkey solution.

Comment: Err...ok, but before next release I'm stuck!:D

Answer (score 0):

You might want to setup OpenVPN server at home. 

It's faster because you don't have to connect through Team Viewer server.